# Have Adobe changed Flash's ExternalInterface marshalling?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an application written in ActionScript 3 which has to run on all versions of the Flash runtime, including the latest - Flash 18.

One section of my code passes a rather complex object (actually a tree of objects) from AS3 to JS via ExternalInterface.call(). The object has internal cyclic references, and it always used to work, up to and including Flash version 17.

In Flash 18 this object no longer gets passed, there is a very long pause, and a stack overflow is thrown. Upon further inspection (with the debugger and FlashBuilder) I find that the pause is in a toJSON method getting called recursively (obviously not correctly handling the cycles in my object).

The documentation for ExternalInterface states that marshalling is done using XML and in the past I've had problems when I've tried to marshal data that can't be represented easily in XML but would work in JSON, I now appear to be having the opposite issue, and this is quite a backward step if cyclic references in existing compiled applications will now break.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Do we know if this is intentional, permanent, and/or documented? It doesn't appear in the release notes for Flash 18, so far as I can see.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [Flash Player 18 release notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_18_air_18_release_notes.html) but changes to `ExternalInterface` related to JSON have definitely happened in the past without documentation. However, usually the Flash Player supports legacy behavior (if it's not a security vulnerability) if you target older SWF versions. Have you changed your SWF target version?

Comment: Maybe then you should change how serialization works against your complex object? Maybe you can hide some properties that would make object recursively serialize itself (say parent-child relations, `this.child.parent==this` and this calls an infinite recursion)? While yes, this can just be a bug in Flash 18.

Comment: @Aaron I'm targetting 12.0 (SWF version 23) as I always have been. The same compiled SWF works on 17 and fails on 18 on the same machine.

Comment: @Vesper that's what I've had to do, removing a lot of the useful structure in order to allow it to be encoded in JSON instead of XML. I just feel it would be nice for Adobe to let us know when they change something fundamental.

Comment: Hmm, how come encoding in JSON is different than encoding in XML? I'd say you need to draw dependency graph of your object's structure and don't expose links for serialization if they lead to the structure graph having cycles. You can survive with full structure this way, just rebuild those links you've not saved at restoration time. See [`IExternalizable`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html) for details.

Comment: @Vesper the serialized data is a view a crosslinked family of objects, with cycles. XML allows references, and the ExternalInterface XML serializer handles them correctly. JSON simply doesn't have the syntax for cycles. The "useful structure" is the cross and back links showing the references within the tree. I've simply had to dump all of that and provide a significantly flattened view of the tree, providing only the base data and then have other callbacks that can provide additional information if needed. It's less efficient, and requires more of the JS developer using our app but it works.